# Equation for the line joining north pole and a point on the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

If I have a complex number in the z-plane and I want to find the equation of the line joining the north pole $(0,0,1)$ of the unit sphere and the complex number $(z=x+iy)$ on the x-y plane should be $$r=<0,0,1>+t<x,y,-1>$$ using the parametric equation of a line.
But the professor gave us a different equation:

$t(0,0,1)+(1-t)(x,y,0)$

This doesn't seem right nor can I find a justification for it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same up to a change of variables $t \mapsto 1-t$.

Combining the vectors in your equation, you get:
$$\langle 0,0,1\rangle + t\langle x,y,-1\rangle = \langle tx,ty,1-t\rangle.$$

Combining the vectors in your professor's equation:
$$t\langle 0,0,1\rangle + (1-t) \langle x,y,0\rangle = \langle (1-t)x,(1-t)y, t\rangle.$$

Notice that these are the same except $t$ has been replaced by $1-t$.

In general the line segment between $\bf x$ and $\bf y$ can be parametrized by ${\bf x} + t({\bf y}-{\bf x})$ or by $t{\bf x} + (1-t){\bf y}$ for $0 \leq t \leq 1$. For a fixed value of $t$, the first equation gives you the point "$t$ of the way" to $\bf y$ from $\bf x$, while the second gives you the point "$t$ of the way" to $\bf x$ from $\bf y$.* You can think of it as a describing a weighted average of the points $\bf x$ and $\bf y$, for every possible combination of weights between $0$ and $1$ that sum to $1$.

*Here when I say "$t$ of the way" I don't mean in terms of absolute distance, but as a fraction of the distance between $\bf x$ and $\bf y$.

Answer (score 1):

The general equation for a line joining the points $P$ and $Q$ is $t P + (1 - t) Q,$ where $t \in \mathbb{R},$ hence your professor's equation. In fact, note that this is exactly the form you also got since $(x, y, -1) = (x, y, 0) - (0, 0, 1),$ so that $(0, 0, 1) + t(x, y, -1) = t(x, y, 0) + (1 - t)(0, 0, 1),$ which is of course the same thing as before. The main point of my answer would be that there are different ways to get the equation of a line: you can express it as the all the convex combinations of two points on it (as your professor did) or you could write it as the points you get by starting at a point and going in a certain direction. Hope this helps. :)